# How to use NSNotificationCenter in Swift correctly?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have a function in Swift to know if reachability/network connection changes..but when I change wifi to 3g this not detect any changes, and I don't know why this is not called..
I have this in viewDidLoad:

```
var kReachabilityChangedNotification:NSString = "kNetworkReachabilityChangedNotification"
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged:",    name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)

 func reachabilityChanged(sender : AnyObject) {
     instanceOfCustomObject.newtworkType()
}
```

And in Custom object.m:

```
- (void)newtworkType {

NSArray *subviews = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"]subviews];
NSNumber *dataNetworkItemView = nil;

for (id subview in subviews) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView") class]]) {
        dataNetworkItemView = subview;
        break;
    }
}

switch ([[dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"dataNetworkType"]integerValue]) {
    case 0:
        networkConnection = @"No wifi or cellular";
        NSLog(@"No wifi or cellular");
        break;

    case 1:
        networkConnection = @"2G";
        NSLog(@"2G");
        break;

    case 2:
        networkConnection = @"3G";
        NSLog(@"3G");
        break;

    case 3:
        networkConnection = @"4G";
        NSLog(@"4G");
        break;

    case 4:
        networkConnection = @"LTE";
        NSLog(@"LTE");
        break;

    case 5:
        networkConnection = @"Wifi";
        NSLog(@"Wifi");
        break;


    default:
        break;
}}
```

How can I do this correct?

Comment: This is Objective-C not Swift!

Comment: Is Swift with objective c integrated. I only use a function in Objective C: - (void)newtworkType {}

Answer (score 1):

For calling any notification, PostNotificationName method will be used.

Lets assume a condition, we want to call notification method while navigating from one view controller to another on button click.

```
This method will navigate you to second view controller having identifier “Second View”

@IBAction func navigateToSecondView(sender : AnyObject)
{
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", 
                                                bundle: nil)
    let viewC : UIViewController =   
    storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondView") as UIViewController
    presentViewController(viewC as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // Action corresponding to the notification with name "ShowMessage”   
    // will be called 
    let notificationCentre = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationCentre .postNotificationName("ShowMessage", object:nil)
}

Now write this in ViewDidLoad() of SecondViewController :- 

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let notificationCentre = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationCentre.addObserver(self, selector: "showMessage", name:    
    "ShowMessage”, object: nil)
}    

// Add this function in SecondViewController Class
func showMessage()
{
    println(" Show Message View")
}
```

This is how NSNotification work for ViewControllers.
Please try this code.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try notificationCenter in swift using given code :-

```
let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
notificationCenter.addObserver(
self,
selector: "textFieldTextChanged:",
name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification,
object: nil)

func textFieldTextChanged(sender : AnyObject) {
sendButton.enabled = messageField.text.utf16count > 0
}
```

Comment: If I add this into didFinishLaunchingWithOptions on appDelegate I get the next error: -[notif.AppDelegate textFieldTextChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175875d0